# How to open magnificPopup on mouseover with ajax content

Tags: javascript

I am using magnificPopup and opening pop up on link click. I want to open it on mouseover and also load ajax content in pop up. Below is my code. What changes i need to make to make it mouseover and keep showing ajax content.

Javascript:

```
$('.open-popup').magnificPopup({
  type: 'ajax',
  removalDelay: 300,
  callbacks: {
    ajaxContentAdded: function ajaxContentAdded() {
      closePopup();
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="ajax/popup.html" class="open-popup">
    <img src="personal_img.png" alt="">
</a>
```

Comment: Similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43945137/4940910

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magnific popup - how to open it on mouseover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900400/magnific-popup-how-to-open-it-on-mouseover)